# How I create a DataBase in the Splash Screen on Android App?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

How I create a DataBase in the SPLASH SCREEN?

Reason's:

I create a code who validate if my Table's and the Database exists, but this code CRASH when I try to read an inexistence Database (then, the app is closed), because I dont have a method to create.

I need create a database and Table "Users" if not exists (this is the case).

When the database exists and the table exists this app works very nice...

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

// Set the duration of the splash screen
private static final long SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY = 2000;

final Context context = this;

UsersDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    loginDataBaseAdapter=new UsersDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    // Set portrait orientation
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    // Hide title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();
            File dbtest =new File("/data/data/my.example.com/databases/database.db");
            if(dbtest.exists())
            {   
                boolean dbtest1 = UsersDataBaseAdapter.databaseExist();
                if (dbtest1==true){

                    Integer dbtest2= UsersDataBaseAdapter.ExisteTabla();
                    if (dbtest2==0 ){
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                    }else{
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                    }

                }else{
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                }
            }else{





                Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
            // Close the activity so the user won't able to go back this
            // activity pressing Back button
            finish();
        }
    };

    // Simulate a long loading process on application startup.
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
}

}
```

Error message in Log

```
03-11 00:22:09.971: E/Trace(4411): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-11 00:22:27.839: D/AndroidRuntime(4411): Shutting down VM
03-11 00:22:28.069: W/dalvikvm(4411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.exemplozxingintegration/com.example.skysoft.qr.SplashScreenActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at com.example.skysoft.qr.UsersDataBaseAdapter.<init>(UsersDataBaseAdapter.java:56)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at com.example.skysoft.qr.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:28)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-11 00:22:28.281: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     ... 11 more
```

My idea, is JUST CREATE the Database in the Splash Screen

UsersDataBaseAdapter.java

```
public class UsersDataBaseAdapter 
{       

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

    static final String LOGIN = "Users";
    String ID = "IdUser";
    String USERNAME = "UserName";
    String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
    String ETIQUETA = "Etiqueta";
    Integer COUNT = 0;
    static String PATH = "/data/data/my.example.com/databases/database.db";


    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;


    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists Users( IdUser INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  UserName VARCHAR, PASSWORD  VARCHAR, Etiqueta VARCHAR); ";


    public static  SQLiteDatabase db;

    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;

    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private static DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

    public  UsersDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        if(db == null) db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String Query = "Select IdUser, UserName, Etiqueta, PASSWORD From Users LIMIT 1";
        Cursor D = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

        D.moveToFirst();

        ID = D.getString(0);
        USERNAME = D.getString(1);
        ETIQUETA = D.getString(2);
        PASSWORD = D.getString(3);

        String QueryCheck= "select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+"Users"+"'";
        Cursor A = db.rawQuery(QueryCheck, null);
        A.getCount();

        if(A!=null) COUNT = A.getCount();

    }



    public  UsersDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public  UsersDataBaseAdapter read() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }



    public void insertRecords(String userName,String password, Integer uid)
    {
       ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

       // Asigna los valores para cada "row" (la fila).
        newValues.put(USERNAME, userName);
        newValues.put(PASSWORD, password);
        newValues.put(ID, uid);

        // Inserta el "row" (la fila) en la tabla
        db.insert(LOGIN, null, newValues);
        ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void updateEti(String userName, String etiqueta)
    {
        // Define la actualización del contenido del "row" (fila).
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        // Asigna los valores de cada "row" (fila).
        updatedValues.put(USERNAME, userName);
        updatedValues.put(ETIQUETA, etiqueta);

        String where=USERNAME+" = ?";
        db.update(LOGIN,updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});             
    }

    //
    public static Boolean CheckTable() {

        SQLiteDatabase helppo = db;
        Cursor cursor = helppo.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+LOGIN+"'", null);
        if(cursor!=null) {
            if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                                cursor.close();
                return true;
            }
                        cursor.close();
        }
        return false;

    }


    public String CheckEtiqueta(String LOGIN2) {

        String Query = "Select * Form Users LIMIT 1";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
             //Sample operation with the Database
             if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("IdUser"))!=null) { 

                   return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("IdUser"));
             }
        }
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("IdUser"));

    }

    public static String getIDUsuario(){
        String Query = "Select * From Users LIMIT 1";
        Cursor D = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

        D.moveToFirst();

        String Var1 = D.getString(0);

        return Var1;
    }

    public static String getUsuario(){
        String Query = "Select * From Users LIMIT 1";
        Cursor D = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

        D.moveToFirst();

        String Var1 = D.getString(1);

        return Var1;
    }

    public static String getPassword(){
        String Query = "Select * From Users LIMIT 1";
        Cursor D = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

        D.moveToFirst();

        String Var1 = D.getString(2);

        return Var1;
    }

    public static String getEtiqueta(){
        String Query = "Select * From Users LIMIT 1";
        Cursor D = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

        D.moveToFirst();

        String Var1 = D.getString(3);

        return Var1;
    }


    public static boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/my.example.com/databases/database.db", null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            checkDB.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database doesn't exist yet.
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }



    public static SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return db;
    }

    public static boolean databaseExist()
    {

        String DB_PATH=PATH;

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            checkDB.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e) {
            // Log an info message stating database doesn't exist.
        }

        return false;
    }

    boolean isTableExists(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) 
    {
        if (tableName == null || db == null || !db.isOpen()) {
            return false; 
            }
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = ? AND name = ?", 
                new String[] {"table", tableName});
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            return false; 
        } 
        int count = cursor.getInt(0); 
        cursor.close(); 
        return count > 0; 
    }

    public static int ExisteTabla(){

        String Query = "Select * From Users LIMIT 1";
        Cursor D = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

        D.moveToFirst();
        int Var1 = D.getCount();

        return Var1;
    }
```

DataBaseHelper.java

```
    public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version) 
        {
               super(context, name, factory, version);
}
    // Manda llamar cuando la base de datos  NO existe en disco y el "helper class" (La clase auxiliar) requiere
    // crear uno nuevo.

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
{
        _db.execSQL(UsersDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);

}
// Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
// of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
{
        // Log the version upgrade.
        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");


        // Actualiza la base de datos existente para conformar la nueva version. Multiple
        // Puede realizar por comparacion de los valores entre los _oldVersion y _newVersion
        // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
        // Create a new one.
        onCreate(_db);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your `UsersDataBaseAdapter ` class.  Your problem is a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Ready! I post th UsersDataBaseAdapter

Comment: Hmm, post your `DataBaseHelper` class too.  Where do you use  `DATABASE_CREATE `?

Comment: One moment please, Yes I use a DATABASE_CREATE in the DataBaseHelper,

Comment: This is most specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably you do not have any data in the database which makes D.moveToFirst(); caused an error

change it to

```
if (D.moveToFirst()){
    ID = D.getString(0);
    USERNAME = D.getString(1);
    ETIQUETA = D.getString(2);
    PASSWORD = D.getString(3);
}
```

Comment: Very Nice man!, The app not crash anymore!!! very cool man! I want to upgrade your "Reputation" (but i'm new & I need 15 in for VoteUp! )

Comment: Hi again, sorry but my app now crash! in the second activitym because don't have Strings!

Comment: dont have String? You better ask another question so that you could post your code and error log